# SwiftUI list not updating

Tags: macos, swiftui

when I run the code below and click on an account it shows all of the journalLines associated with the account.  if I click the add button it updates the list of journalLines with the new journalLines.  But only once.  when I click it again it increases the balance but does not update the list of lines. if you click another account and then click back you will see the full list.  but it only auto updates the list once?

I tried replacing `account.lines` in the list with `self.shared.journalLines.filter({$0.accountID == account.id})` but I got the same behavior.

is this a bug or did I miss something? if it is a bug what is the workaround?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var shared:SharedObject

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {self.shared.test()}) {Text("Add")}
                List(self.shared.accounts) { account in
                    NavigationLink(destination:
                        List(self.shared.journalLines.filter({$0.accountID == account.id})) { line in
                            HStack {
                                Text(line.payee)
                                Spacer()
                                Text("$ \(line.amount, specifier: "%.2f")")
                            }
                        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    ) {
                        HStack {
                            Text(account.name)
                            Spacer()
                            Text("$ \(account.balance, specifier: "%.2f")")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 200)
            }
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }

}

struct Account:Identifiable {
    @ObservedObject var shared:SharedObject
    var id:Int
    var name:String
    var lines:[JournalLine] {
        return self.shared.journalLines.filter({$0.accountID == self.id})
    }
    var balance:Double {
        return self.lines.map({$0.amount}).reduce(0){$0+$1}
    }
}
struct JournalLine:Identifiable {
    @ObservedObject var shared:SharedObject
    let id:UUID = UUID()
    var payee:String
    var accountID:Int
    var amount:Double
}

class SharedObject:ObservableObject {
    @Published var accounts:[Account] = []
    @Published var journalLines:[JournalLine] = []

    init() {

        self.accounts.append(Account(shared: self,id: 1, name: "Account#1"))
        self.accounts.append(Account(shared: self,id: 2, name: "Account#2"))
        self.accounts.append(Account(shared: self,id: 3, name: "Account#3"))

        self.journalLines.append(JournalLine(shared: self, payee: "Payee1", accountID: 1, amount: 100))
        self.journalLines.append(JournalLine(shared: self, payee: "Payee2", accountID: 1, amount: 200))
        self.journalLines.append(JournalLine(shared: self, payee: "Payee3", accountID: 2, amount: 300))
        self.journalLines.append(JournalLine(shared: self, payee: "Payee4", accountID: 2, amount: 400))
        self.journalLines.append(JournalLine(shared: self, payee: "Payee5", accountID: 3, amount: 500))
        self.journalLines.append(JournalLine(shared: self, payee: "Payee6", accountID: 3, amount: 600))

    }

    func test() {
        self.journalLines.append(JournalLine(shared: self, payee: "Payee10", accountID: 1, amount: 100))
        self.journalLines.append(JournalLine(shared: self, payee: "Payee10", accountID: 2, amount: 100))
        self.journalLines.append(JournalLine(shared: self, payee: "Payee10", accountID: 3, amount: 100))
    }

}
```

edit: revised code with suggestions from comments. Still getting the same errors with the changes implemented

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var shared:SharedObject

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {self.shared.test()}) {Text("Add")}.padding()
                List {
                    ForEach(self.shared.accounts) { account in
                        NavigationLink(destination:
                            List {
                                ForEach(self.shared.journalLines.filter({$0.accountID == account.id})) { line in
                                    HStack {
                                        Text(line.payee)
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text("$ \(line.amount, specifier: "%.2f")")
                                    }
                                }
                            }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                        ) {
                            HStack {
                                Text(account.name)
                                Spacer()
                                Text("$ \(self.shared.journalLines.filter({$0.accountID == account.id}).map({$0.amount}).reduce(0){$0+$1}, specifier: "%.2f")")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 200)
            }
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }

}

class Account:Identifiable {
    init(id:Int,name:String) {
        self.id=id
        self.name=name
    }
    var id:Int
    var name:String
}
class JournalLine:Identifiable {
    init(payee:String,accountID:Int,amount:Double) {
        self.payee=payee
        self.accountID=accountID
        self.amount=amount
    }
    let id:UUID = UUID()
    var payee:String
    var accountID:Int
    var amount:Double
}

class SharedObject:ObservableObject {
    @Published var accounts:[Account] = []
    @Published var journalLines:[JournalLine] = []

    init() {

        self.accounts.append(Account(id: 1, name: "Account#1"))
        self.accounts.append(Account(id: 2, name: "Account#2"))
        self.accounts.append(Account(id: 3, name: "Account#3"))

        self.journalLines.append(JournalLine(payee: "Payee1", accountID: 1, amount: 100))
        self.journalLines.append(JournalLine(payee: "Payee2", accountID: 1, amount: 200))
        self.journalLines.append(JournalLine(payee: "Payee3", accountID: 2, amount: 300))
        self.journalLines.append(JournalLine(payee: "Payee4", accountID: 2, amount: 400))
        self.journalLines.append(JournalLine(payee: "Payee5", accountID: 3, amount: 500))
        self.journalLines.append(JournalLine(payee: "Payee6", accountID: 3, amount: 600))

    }

    func test() {
        self.journalLines.append(JournalLine(payee: "Payee10", accountID: 1, amount: 100))
        self.journalLines.append(JournalLine(payee: "Payee10", accountID: 2, amount: 100))
        self.journalLines.append(JournalLine(payee: "Payee10", accountID: 3, amount: 100))
    }

}
```

Comment: are you testing on simulator?

Comment: @jawadAli no not running it in a simulator. it is a Mac app that I am running on my Mac

Comment: working fine on mac tested

Comment: @jawadAli what version of Xcode/Mac do you have?

Comment: why did this get down voted?  perfectly legit question and I explained correctly.

Answer (score 7):

It's a common issue i observed in SwiftUI's List/LazyVStack.

I used a simple trick to fix this issue. **Assign a UniqueID to the view you wanted to update dynamically.**

Example with List:

```
List(items, id: \.self) {
  Text($0.name)
}
 .id(UUID())
```

Example with LazyVStack:

```
LazyVStack {
  ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in 
     Text(item.name)
  }
}
 .id(UUID())
```

Comment: Simply use UUID() would make the list not stable, it will redraw for some particular situation. For example when I show a confirmationDialog before deleting, the dialog will appear twice, and it's pretty strange.
My solution is making the item Hashable and take all the attributes into account when calculating the hash. Then use `\.self` as id of the List elements is enough. e.g. `ForEach(items, id: \.self)`

Answer (score 3):

**Answer**

I do not know if it is a bug or feature but List is kind of static which means do not look for updates. If you want to track updates a common workaround for now is placing ForEach inside List. This way your view gets updated each time you update your `@Published` object.

Here is how to do the list + foreach part https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/building-a-menu-using-list

Comment: thank you for your response.  I added foreach under the list and still has the same behavior.

Comment: Could be for several reasons, probably the same reason you get downvoted. You should design your backend differently. You actually create shared object with structs that have sharedObject which means two object contains each other. In my opinion you should get compilation error. Also you should note that two List means you need two foreach to update both of them. Not sure why Account + Journal contain sharedObject. In my opinion you should remove sharedobject from both, no reason for them Change your enviromentobject to observedobject (no reason for enviromentobject according to snippet)

Comment: In my opinion You need that shared object with two Published variable array. Define that two Variable array as simple classes (classes! not struct) And List {} using ForEach inside as to the hackingswift url

Comment: Apple recommendation struct for model. Which is why account and journalline are structs. The shared object reference is so that account can query the journallines from the shared object. Also shared is an environmentobject available to all views.

Comment: I edited the original post to include the revised code that includes all of your suggestions and I am still getting the issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209303/discussion-between-zahovay-and-eleethesontai).

Answer (score 3):

List needs important changes such removal, appending, or replacing, otherwise will not update the view. when you replace a single item in the list the unique id has to change, if not the view update will not take place. So,

```
let listindex = bildList.firstIndex(of: listitem)
bildList[listindex!].itemname = "new name"
bildList[listindex!].id = UUID()
```

After the current item's id changed, the view will be refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

If you use id: .self it will update the list each time something changes, not just when a new list item is added.

```
List(assetManager.reminders, id: \.self) { collection in
                        ReminderListCell(collection)
                            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 15, bottom: 10, trailing: 15))
                            .listRowBackground(Color.clear.background(.ultraThinMaterial))
                            .swipeActions(edge: .trailing, allowsFullSwipe: false){
                                Button(action: {assetManager.deleteSubcollection(named: collection)}, label: {Image(systemName: "trash").foregroundColor(.red)})
                            }
```